# Change String in the Input.txt File in Java without creating Output.txt

Tags: java, netbeans-8

How can I change a text in the file without creating a new one?

I'm creating a pacman game for our project. 
I created Map.txt file that contains the map and the current progress.

When the player step on the letter f = fruits it will change into g = grass.

Comment: What have you tried?  What are you having trouble with?  Can you provide a simple and concise piece of code we could run so we can see what the problem is?

Comment: should i put all the codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the map from a file upon game initialization. Once the map is loaded in memory, you can change the values depending on the game logic. Your file, map.txt doesn't need to change.

If you wish to save your game with the current memory values, you can also do that too.

Here is an example of a 2 dimensional String array to hold your map info and I show you how to change your map as the player moves around the maze:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class PacMan extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected static final int NUM_ROWS = 14;
    protected static final int NUM_COLUMNS = 14;
    protected static String MAP[][];

    protected static JLabel status = new JLabel("Points: 0");

    public PacMan() {
        super("Pac Man");

        initializeMap();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().add(new GamePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(status, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        pack();
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initializeMap() {
        int row = 0;
        MAP = new String[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLUMNS];

        BufferedReader reader = null; 
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("map.txt")));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] columns = line.split(" ");
                if(columns.length == NUM_COLUMNS) {
                    for(int column = 0; column < columns.length; column++) {
                        MAP[row][column] = columns[column];
                    }
                }
                row++;
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new PacMan();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });     
    }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BufferedImage grass;
    private BufferedImage wall;
    private BufferedImage apple;
    private BufferedImage man;

    private int points = 0;
    private int currentPlayerRow = 1;
    private int currentPlayerCol = 1;

    public GamePanel() {
        try {
            addKeyListener(this);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

            grass = ImageIO.read(new File("grass.png"));
            wall = ImageIO.read(new File("wall.png"));
            apple = ImageIO.read(new File("apple.png"));
            man = ImageIO.read(new File("man.png"));
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // first, draw all grass in the screen to take advantage
        // of transparent images...
        for(int r = 0; r < PacMan.NUM_ROWS; r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < PacMan.NUM_COLUMNS; c++) {
                g.drawImage(grass, c * 32, r * 32, null);
            }
        }

        // now just draw all objects (except grass) currently in map. you can 
        // change objects in the map array depending on your game logic elsewhere
        for(int r = 0; r < PacMan.NUM_ROWS; r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < PacMan.NUM_COLUMNS; c++) {
                if(!PacMan.MAP[r][c].equals("0")) {
                    g.drawImage(getImage(PacMan.MAP[r][c]), c * 32, r * 32, null);
                }
            }
        }       
    }

    private Image getImage(String string) {

        if(string.equals("0")){
            return grass;
        }
        else if(string.equals("a")){
            return apple;
        }
        else if(string.equals("m")){
            return man;
        }       
        else {
            if(string.equals("1")){
                return wall;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(PacMan.NUM_COLUMNS * 32, PacMan.NUM_ROWS * 32);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}  
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && !PacMan.MAP[currentPlayerRow][currentPlayerCol - 1].equals("1")) {
            PacMan.MAP[currentPlayerRow][currentPlayerCol] = "0";
            --currentPlayerCol;
        }
        else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && !PacMan.MAP[currentPlayerRow][currentPlayerCol + 1].equals("1")) {
            PacMan.MAP[currentPlayerRow][currentPlayerCol] = "0";
            ++currentPlayerCol;
        }
        else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP && !PacMan.MAP[currentPlayerRow - 1][currentPlayerCol].equals("1")) {
            PacMan.MAP[currentPlayerRow][currentPlayerCol] = "0";
            --currentPlayerRow;
        }
        else {
            if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && !PacMan.MAP[currentPlayerRow + 1][currentPlayerCol].equals("1")) {
                PacMan.MAP[currentPlayerRow][currentPlayerCol] = "0";
                ++currentPlayerRow;
            }
        }

        if(PacMan.MAP[currentPlayerRow][currentPlayerCol].equals("a")){
            points += 10;
            PacMan.status.setText("Points: " + points);
        }

        PacMan.MAP[currentPlayerRow][currentPlayerCol] = "m";
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Here is the map.txt that stores your 14x14 tile information as text:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 m 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 a 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 a 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 a 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 a 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

And finally, a screenshot using my own 32 pixel tiles (You can use your own 32x32 pixel tiles, though...

[image]

Comment: i will post all my code. help me fix it :) thanks. i really appreciate your help.

Comment: It might be easier to use a 2 dimensional array to paint your maze, no?

Comment: Yes, but our instructor wants to use the text file. Haha. Wew

Comment: Thanks :) i'll try to implement that with my code. :)

Comment: thank you so much sir. you are awesome :D thanks you so much :)

Comment: i will post some question again sir, im developing a scheduling system using java for my senior thesis. i hope you'll be able to help me again. thank you :)

Comment: If this answered your question, why not accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
PrintWriter mywriter = new PrintWriter("thisismytextfile.txt", "UTF-8");
mywriter.println("I'm writing to txt-file");
mywriter.close();
```

this will produce a txt file and overwrite the file if it already exists.

next time provide some of your code first.

Comment: Im sorry im noob at Java. Can i ask? what the purpose of the "UTF-8" Thanks :)

Comment: It's the character set that is used inside of the file. Roughly you could say it defines how the bytes of the file are converted to characters when reading the file or the other way around when saving the file.

Comment: i will post all my code. help me fix it its contain 4 class :) thanks. i really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Main class
package Maze; 

import javax.swing.*;

public class Maze{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Maze();
    }

    public Maze(){  //setup the frame of the maze
        JFrame f = new JFrame();   //create the frame
        f.setTitle("Maze Game");   //title of the frame
        f.add(new Board());
        f.setSize(464, 485);       //(width,height) the size of the screen
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  //place the position of the screen in the middle
        f.setVisible(true);        // so that we can see the screen
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   //to close the window
    }
}
```

Comment: by the way you need to create the image 32x32 pixels and Map.text 14 x 14 in the project folder. im using netbeans 8